# Applying an unbiased estimator by using a linear function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ by a a sample from a Uniform Distribution $(0,\theta)$ where $\theta > 0$ is an unknown parameter.

How do I construct an unbiased estimator by applying a linear function to each of the sample mean $\bar{X}$ and nth order statics $X_{(n)}$.

I have calculated the Expectation and Variance of $\bar{X}$:

$E(\bar{X})=\frac{\theta}{2}$

$Var(\bar{X})=\frac{\theta^2}{12}$

I have calculated the Expectation and Variance of $X_{(n)}$:

$E(X_{(n)})=\frac{n}{n+1}\theta$

$Var(X_{(n)})=\frac{n}{(n+1)^2}\theta^2$

Comment: Is $X_{(n)}$ is the maximum of sample? Also of what are you trying to make an unbiased estimate of?

Comment: @sudeep5221 $X_{(n)}$ is the nth order statistics. And I am trying to make an unbiased estimator to each of the $\bar{X}$ and $X_{(n)}$

EDIT:
I have edited the question to address the confusion. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An estimator $\hat \theta$ of some parameter $\theta$ is unbiased if $$\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta] = \theta.$$  That is to say, the expected value of the estimator is equal to the parameter.  Since you found the expectation of the sample mean $\bar X$ is $$\operatorname{E}[\bar X] = \theta/2,$$ is there a constant that you can multiply $\bar X$ by that would change the right hand side to $\theta$?  Recall that $$\operatorname{E}[cX] = c \operatorname{E}[X]$$ for some fixed constant $c$.  Once you find this constant, then this will provide an estimator for $\theta$ that is based on the sample mean.

Similarly, for the maximum order statistic $X_{(n)}$, what could you multiply by?  Note here that $n$ is still a constant--it is presumed that the sample size is fixed and known, thus with respect to the expectation of a sample statistic, it is also constant.

Comment: How would I write that ? $\hat{\theta}=2\bar{X}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\frac{n+1}{n}X_{(n)}$

Comment: No, the estimator is what you are taking the expectation of, so in the first case it is 2 times the sample mean.  In the second case you cannot continue to use 2.  What did you multiply by for that one?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it

Comment: @Jerry Yes, those are correct.

Comment: okay thank you!